# Monitor not waking up on start

Tags: multi-monitor, display, manjaro, displayport

I have two monitors (both are [Dell u2515](https://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2515h-monitor/pd)); they are connected to the motherboard by a daisy-chain cable, both DP 1.2, but I cannot get both of my monitors to wake up on start.

The mointor connected directly is in a sleep state when booting the OS ([Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/), Linux 4.14), but the one daisy-chained from this wakes as expected.

They can both be forced to wake up using:

```
xset -display :1 dpms force off
```

This causes both to sleep and, on keypress, wake up successfully.

DP 1.2 is enabled on the monitor connected to the motherboard and disabled on the other.

Might this be related to multi-monitor? under Linux or specifically daisy chained DP

XRandR output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1200x960      59.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1200x960      59.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Thanks